# Retrieving Windows 8 product key

Tags: c#, c++, windows-8

**Main Goal**:

As the title says I would like a way to retrieve the windows 8 product
key. A C# example would be preferable but C++ would work as well. If
anyone has a solution in some other form if you could post it perhaps
I can figure it out.

**Reasoning**:

I have been recently put in charge of maintaining the company laptops.
The previous person in charge did not keep track of the MSDN keys
assigned. I would like to build a catalog of each and every product
serial including the installed operating system. Currently unless
using a ghost image or other means I'd have to use a new serial After
spending a few hours on Google I already have many ways to get all
previous versions of Windows except eight. Such as [*Retrieve Windows
Seven Product Key*](http://blog.psychocoder.net/2012/07/04/retrieve-your-windows-product-key-with-csharp/)

Comment: This would be a perfect task for PowerShell.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. While I am experienced with PowerShell I can get around in C# a lot faster. I'll build the initial quick app without but may look into PowerShell later. It could prove a good experience with easier deployment. Thank you for your input Matt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this sample application is compatible to retrieve windows 8 product keys but you could at least give it a shot and see if it works or not

Its called Windows Product Key Finder and its available at codeplex:

```
A small tool for finding your Windows product key. No install required, just a single executable file. 
Its open source so you can actually see what the program is doing with your key :P
```

http://wpkf.codeplex.com/

Comment: This is great thank you. I tried this before and it only showed me the serial that windows shows "Computer->Properties". I completely missed the "Find Key" button so I discarded it. Opps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to query -

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Win8\ProductKey
```

Follow the below thread -

[Accessing the Windows registry using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470770/accessing-the-windows-registry-using-net)