# Winform application not running on 64bit server

Tags: winforms, registry, manifest, uac, windows64

I have a winform application to read values from the registrykey..

so i know i have to run as administrator in order to do so.

I have two servers of win 2003. one is 32 bit and the other is 64 bit.

When i run this application on my 32 bit i have no problem and it reads the values from the registry..

but when i run the application from my 64 bit server it cannot read from the registry.

i get a

> system.nullreferenceexception

as i cannot read the root of my reg key which returns null.

i have put a manifest file also but with that too its not working..

any help will be greatly appreciated... thanks..

here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1 assembly.adaptive.xsd" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:co.v1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1">
 <asmv1:assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.31" name="FileShareMgmt.exe" publicKeyToken="0000000000000000" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" type="win32" />
<application />
<entryPoint>
<assemblyIdentity name="FileShareMgmt" version="1.0.0.0" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" />
<commandLine file="FileShareMgmt.exe" parameters="" />
</entryPoint>
<trustInfo>
<security>
  <applicationRequestMinimum>
    <PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet" version="1"  Unrestricted="true" ID="Custom" SameSite="site" />
    <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="Custom" />
  </applicationRequestMinimum>
  <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">       
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
    <!-- UAC Manifest Options
        If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
        requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

        If you want to utilize File and Registry Virtualization for backward 
        compatibility then delete the requestedExecutionLevel node.
    -->     
  </requestedPrivileges>
</security>
</trustInfo>
```

this is not the complete manifest as there are  which i think wont be required to show here...

Comment: We'll have to see the source code probably to figure this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you verified that the key you're trying to read exists on the 64-bit system?

The path may be different for a 64-bit system: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896459

If your registry key contains the text "WOW6432node", that's the 32-bit version. The 64-bit version will probably be the same except that part of the path won't be there.

This question may be related: [Why is OpenSubKey() returning null on my Windows 7 64-bit system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464358/why-is-opensubkey-returning-null-on-my-win-7-64-bit-system)

Comment: thanks... the problem was in building i had to use x86.. which makes me wonder why do i need the manifest to "requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" "