# Registry Redirection C# on with older .net versions x64

Tags: c#, .net, registrykey

How do I open the `HKLM\Software\myApp` key (x86) and `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\myApp` key (x64) in C# using the same code. I've read about `OpenBaseKey`, **but unfortunately I have an earlier version of .Net, not 4+.**

I've tried the below code because I expected (like in C++) that the path would be automatically resolved, but it seems it wasn't.

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software");
key = key.OpenSubKey("myApp");
if (key == null) // <<<< key is null on x64 machines
    return false;
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217199/what-are-some-alternatives-to-registrykey-openbasekey-in-net-3-5

Comment: It is available since 4.0, getting stuck on 6+ year old version of free software is a problem you can't get help with.  The other obvious workaround is to change the Platform target to AnyCPU so the redirector doesn't redirect.

Comment: but i WANT to get redirected