# cannot write to the registry key

Tags: c#

I am getting error cannot write to the registry key when i am trying to save my keys in the registry .

//Here is my code .

Note : I tried to run as an Administartor assuming some permission problems still getting the same error ....

```
private const string RegistryKeyName = "Skms";
private readonly RegistryKey SoftwareKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE");

public KeyManagementRegistryKeyChangeImpl(bool writeable)
    {
        this.writable = writeable;
        RegistryKey skms; 
        if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem == true) 
        {
            skms = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64).OpenSubKey(RegistryKeyName,true);

        }
        else
        {
            skms = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32);
        }

        if (null == skms)
        {
            skms = SoftwareKey.CreateSubKey(RegistryKeyName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
        }

        if(skms == null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                @"Registry Key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\{0}' not found or created",
                RegistryKeyName));
        }

        Decryptor decryptor = Decryptor.Create();
```

Comment: do you mean that after `skms = SoftwareKey.CreateSubKey(RegistryKeyName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);` `skms` is still null?

Comment: @Russ C  It says Cannot write to the registry key .

Comment: @Michael Sagalovich  Yes it is still null .

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: @Shalini WHAT says "Cannot write to the registry key"? Exception is thrown? Or what?

Comment: Is there any problem with the 64-bit or something because it's been working for 32-bit systems but not in 64-bit systems

Comment: @ Michael Sagalovich  My error message now changed to Registry Key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Skms' not found or created . After i change to  RegistryKey skms = SoftwareKey.OpenSubKey(RegistryKeyName);
            if (null == skms)
            {
                skms = SoftwareKey.OpenSubKey(RegistryKeyName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
            }

Comment: have a look at this.. it may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074411/how-to-open-a-wow64-registry-key-from-a-64-bit-net-application

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
if (null == skms)            
{             
   skms = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE",true);              
   RegistryKey key = skms.CreateSubKey(
          RegistryKeyName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);      
}
```

This is the answer for my question .

Comment: may I ask why `null` is the first value in your compiration ? is there any meaning to that ?

Comment: @itsho, some people prefer to put the 'constant' in a comparison before the variable in the comparision, 'myvar == someconstant' is the same as 'someconstant == myvar', but avoids a mistype of 'myvar = someconstant', which will evaulation to 'true', but will not be the intent of the programmer, and the compiler will not tell you anything is wrong. 'someconstant = myvar' will result in a compiler error on the other hand

Comment: That is not the answer to your question at all.

Comment: The second parameter (true) to OpenSubKey seems to be the answer to your question

Answer (score 105):

Try this:

```
RegistryKey skms = SoftwareKey.OpenSubKey(RegistryKeyName, true);
```

The second parameter should be set to true if you need write access to the key.

-EDIT-

On 64-bit system, you can try this (if you are using .Net 4):

```
private readonly RegistryKey SoftwareKey = 
    RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64).
    OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE");
```

Comment: @ Edwin de Koning   Registry Key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Skms' not found or created I am getting this new error after i try giving OpenSubKey

Comment: @ShaliniPavan: Try to open the "SOFTWARE" key with the 'true' parameter as well.

Comment: @ Edwin de Koning : I am still getting the same error and this been working fine in 32-bit systems only for 64-bit systems it is throwing me error

Comment: Thanks @Edwin de Koning : but no luck

Comment: "but no luck". If you gave us some helpful information, I'd try to help.

Comment: I mean to say still i am getting  same error even if i try to place piece of code given my you in my application. It says Cannot write to the registry key and when i check SoftwareKey.GetSubKeyNames() the "skms" is not in the list . I am not able to figure it out actually .

Comment: @EdwindeKoning you definitely solved my issue. Who would have thought there would be a true parameter just so I can write

Comment: Actually CreateSubKey will either create it if missing or open it in write mode, so you just need to use create if the situation is indeterminate

Answer (score 7):

You are probably falling foul of registry redirection. Perhaps you have a 32 bit process on a 64 bit system and writes to HKLM\Software get redirected to HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node.

You need to open the 64 bit key directly, or compile for AnyCPU.

Comment: If I compile for AnyCPU I am getting the following error  :  The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 ' provider is not registered in the local machine

Comment: Either register and use the 64 Jet, or stay with x86 and open the 64 bit view of registry.

Comment: For the latter look at the RegistryView enumeration if you target .net 4. Otherwise you have to Pinvoke, believe it or not.

Comment: @bathineni : Thanks for your reply but i am still getting a problem . I am able to read the registry key if i manually give in wow6432 bit node but not able to create the key through my application .

Comment: Don't hard code Wow6432node. That is very strongly discouraged by MS. You should use the RegistryView enumeration if you are on .net 4. Otherwise you need to P/invoke. I don't feel inclined to spend much more time on this since you still won't tell us what your configuration is. Are you on 64 bit OS? Is your process 32 or 64 bit? Do you want to write to 32 or 64 bit view of registry? Without those details you are just wasting our time.

Comment: I am sorry thats my mistake. Application is working fine on 32-bit systems and i am trying to run on 64-bit systems where i am getting error cannot write to the registry key . And i didnt hardcode Wow6432Node i said i hardcoded key in Wow6432 node which i am able to read it and is working fine if i want to create the key through my appln its giving me error .Please see my edited code above for clear stand .

Comment: Can you tell me the name of the key on a 32 bit system, and the name of the key in a 64 bit system?

Comment: Name of the key is "Skms" in both 32-bit and 64-bit

Comment: give me the full paths please

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Skms FOR 64- BIT

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \\SOFTWARE\\Skms for 32-bit

Answer (score 4):

try this......someone may find useful....

```
using System.Security;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using Microsoft.Win32;

string user = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;

RegistryKey rk = 
RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64).
OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE",true);    

RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();

rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(user,
            RegistryRights.WriteKey | RegistryRights.ReadKey | RegistryRights.Delete,
            InheritanceFlags.None,
            PropagationFlags.None,
            AccessControlType.Allow));
rk = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("RegistryRightsExample", 
            RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.Default, rs);
```