# NullReferenceException at RegistryKey

Tags: c#

I want to read from Registry and set some Values, but i keep getting NullReferenceExceptions.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    RegistryKey rkApp = null;
    RegistryKey settings = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
        settings = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Shit", true);

        if (settings.GetValue("automove") != null)
        {
            automove = true;
            autostartToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

i deleted some unrelevant code in this example but this is my code... Any Ideas?

The error appears in line if `(settings.GetValue("automove") != null)`

Comment: what line is the exception thrown from (examine the `StackTrace` from the exception)

Comment: if (settings.GetValue("automove") != null)

Comment: `settings` isn't `null`?

Comment: Then you know why you're getting a NullReferenceException - your actual question is why settings is null, yes? Context is extremely important for people to be able to answer you quickly and correctly. =)

Comment: why are you trying to open HKLM from HKCU? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.localmachine.aspx

Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074411/how-to-open-a-wow64-registry-key-from-a-64-bit-net-application

Answer (score 4):

```
Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\...
```

The `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` hive doesn't contain a key whose name starts with `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. If you're trying to read from the local machine hive, you'll need to update your code:

```
Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Shit", true)
```

Also, if either the `Wow6432Node` key doesn't exist (maybe you're running on a 32-bit OS?), or doesn't contain a key called `Shit`, then the `OpenSubKey` method will return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it this way:

First, i checked if settings is null. If settings is null then i create the SubKey first.
After this, i re-set the settings variable and evrything is fine.

```
settings = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Shit", true);
if (settings == null)
{
    Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Shit").Flush();
    settings = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Shit", true);
}
```